# Malchut Shamyim working through us?

Tags: commentaries, malchut-royalty, heaven

I learned that "Kabalat Ol Malchut Shamayim"--acceptance of the "yoke" of heaven (accepting the Heavenly Kingdom)--is refering to G-ds rule/reign and thus means 'accepting the the Authority of Heaven'.

But then I read that (the rectification of the) Malchut and Israel are the same thing, for they are her (Malchut) building and her limbs. She emanates through each and every Jew and she is Klal Yisroel, and every rectification of Israel and their actions occur within her, since they are her spirit that has emanated. (Sha'arei Leshem, p. 86)

What does this mean? Does this mean the Malchut (that is, G-ds reign) acts and  becomes visible through the Jewish community? How should I understand this? We need to become a kingdom of priest and a holy nation (Exodus 19:6) and of course He is our King, but how do we together become 'her building and her limbs'?

Comment: Hint: Kabbalistic concepts are NEVER taken literally.

Comment: Can there be a King without a kingdom?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Thank you,  I couldn't figure that one out by myself.. To get serious, what I wanted to know is how I should understand this metaphor, this figure of speech.

Comment: Kabbalah should only be studied under the instruction of a proper teacher, and "beginner" kabbalah books and weird cults like the Kabbalah Centre don't count. @DannySchoemann